# Qt QList ASSERT failure after installing on others PCs

Tags: c++, qt, postgresql, qt4, qlist

I made a setup packadge of some program in Visual Studio 2008. So on my PC after installation everything works well. On others PC when you just click on database connection option it just crashes.

Well, here's the error

[image]

I think it appears at this line

```
database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
```

in database initialization part because of message about DB apperas and everything seems work fine until this line.

Here's full function

```
void DatabaseManagement::initDatabase(){
    QMessageBox::information(this, "error tracking step 5", " DB ADDED");

    database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
    
    QStringList sdrivers = QSqlDatabase::drivers();
    //output all avalible drivers
    QString driver = sdrivers[0];
    for(int i = 0; i< sdrivers.size();i++)
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Driver info", sdrivers[i]);

    
}
```

`database` variable here is global for `DatabaseManagement` class.
Also in this class I got `getDatabase` function which returns `database` variable and I use it in other class, let say in `mainClass` (in case if this could be cause of the problem).

What coulbe be the cause of this problem? How could I solve that?
By the way, I use `Qt 4.7.4`

**UPD:**
Well, the problem solved! I forget to add sqldrivers folder! Of course I added all necessary `.dlls` but for some reason program see it only in this folder. Hope it could be helpful for somebody.
By the way *DependencyWalker* show taht nothing was wrong with not working version (without `sqldrivers` folder).

Comment: Dependency Walker does not see runtime stuff I think. Process Explorer is the tool for that (also otherwise useful in situations where Task Manager just doesn't cut it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that the problem lies here (A debugger would tell you more):

```
QStringList sdrivers = QSqlDatabase::drivers();
//output all available drivers
QString driver = sdrivers[0];
```

You're accessing sdrivers[0] without checking that sdrivers contains at least one element.
I assume you didn't deploy the Qt SQL plugins correctly and thus none is found on the other computer. So fix above code (guarding it with `if (!sdrivers.isEmpty())`) and [deploy the plugins](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-plugins.html).

Comment: yeah problem with plugin deploying, already checked and done! however, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is more likely this line: QString driver = sdrivers[0];
I guess you forgot to provide the sql-plugin folder? %YOUR-APP-PATH%/plugins/qpsql.dll

Try adding:

```
if(sdrivers.size() > 0)
    QString driver = sdrivers[0];
```